# Azure map remove default border / outline

Tags: javascript, css, azure, maps, azure-maps

I am using Azure maps [Azure-Internet of Things-AzureMaps-Create a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-create)

I want to remove the default black outline/border around the map. I looked for the same in
azure maps documentation but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you try setting the style for your map? 

<style>
         html, body {
             margin: 10;
         }

         #myMap {
             height: 100vh;
             width: 100vw;
         }
  
     </style>

If that is not what you are looking for, please share more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to remove the black border/outline by using the following CSS.

```
.mapboxgl-canvas {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map doesn't have a border until it has focus. When it has focus the black border appears. This is an accessibility feature that shouldn't be overridden as you will end up making your application less accessible to certain users.

Comment: @Prashant Tikone If an answer is helpful, please "**Accept answer**" and "**Up-Vote**" for the same which might be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @rbrundritt thank you for your comment. actually we have to remove this border even if it makes our application less accessible to certain users.

Comment: Well, the border is added by the browsers accessibility settings automatically. I have yet to find a CSS setting that overrides it.